# Error with multiprocessing of functions inside function (only when run in PyCharm)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Trying to run multiple functions in parallel inside function. Code executes well when not inside function.

```
from multiprocessing import Process


def main():

    def test1():
        print("test1")

    def test2():
        print("test2")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        p1 = Process(target=test1)
        p2 = Process(target=test2)
        p1.start()
        p2.start()


main()
```

Getting

```
"AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'main.<locals>.test1'"
```

error message in PyCharm. Outside of PyCharm the code works.
What am I missing?

Comment: This code works if I copy it verbatim into https://pyfiddle.io/ it prints both text. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yeah, now I see it's not a problem in code itself.
This is the error message I get in PyCharm:
"AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'main.<locals>.test1'"

Comment: @PatrickArtner ...but I get that error if I try to run that same code in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out answer, although it's not exact one to question I posted.
I made it work with class. It'll do the job for me.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class Main:

    def test1(self):
        print("test1")

    def test2(self):
        print("test2")


mycl = Main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Process(target=mycl.test1)
    p2 = Process(target=mycl.test2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

Comment: You can remove `class Main`, `mycl = Main()` and `mycl.`. You can also remove `if __name__ == "__main__":` if you don't intend this file to be a module.

Comment: @Guimoute I'm getting "AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'main.<locals>.test1'" if i do that.